# Missing middle name in travel documents

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, russia, belarus, austrian-citizens

I know I do have a middle name as it is listed in my birth certificate and I have many documents from my childhood that include it (e.g. school records), it is also used for elections but it was never included in my national identity card or passport.

I'm an Austrian citizen and actually have travelled around many countries where it could have caused problems, but I didn't have any trouble so far, not even in the US. However, I'm planning to travel to Russia and Belarus soon, and I don't know about those countries.

I have a valid national identity card and passport that both show my name without the middle name.

Can this affect any travel, specifically to Russia or Belarus? Do other countries know or care about my middle name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your passport serves as a proof of who you are. It is the leading document for the Russian and Belarussian authorities. Unless say you try to leave the country on a plane where you booked with first-middle-last they are never going to find out that somehow you have a birth certificate that has an extra middle name on it.

So as long as your passport is consistent with other stuff that's around I wouldn't worry. Consider that middle name an unofficial nickname.

On my visum they call my middle name "patronymic" So apparently your middle name customarily comes from your fathers family here.

(I just happen to be in Russia right now).

Comment: Yes, I know about the custom of Patronyms in Russia, Belarus and other countries in that area. It motivated my question as they more commonly ask for that Patronym middle name on forms, like for instance RZD booking... But my middle name is not a Patronym and not even male, like my first name - it is used as a middle name somewhat commonly in Europe e.g. Italy though. I have never booked flights with the middle name.